# jQuery Validation Plugin - error placement - basic bootstrap grids

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

So this is code of my form:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline" id="myform">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

      <label class="col-md-2 vcenter text-center" for="in1">G<sub>t</sub></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Transmitter gain" class="form-control 
      vcenter" id="in1" name="n1" value="">

      <select class="form-control" id="gt_sel" name="gt_si">
          <option value="dbi">dBi</option>
          <option value="dbd">dBd</option>  
      </select>

    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
....
```

and this are settings of plugin

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
},
```

[Image - how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkP5s.png)

I want error text to be placed after the select squares, but I think that in first place my whole form and grid settings in bootstrap aren't like they should be

Comment: if you can put your js, HTML and CSS in https://jsfiddle.net/ it would be easier for people willing to help you.

Comment: Can I somehow add jQuery Validation plugin to jsfiddle, first time using it and I have that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `element.parent().append(error);` to make sure the error always gets appended as the last child.